# I'm trying to calculate the ROI with product revenue and cost, but still given me the wrong value

Tags: looker-studio, roi

I'm trying to calculate the ROI with product revenue and cost:

[image: The formula used for ROI]

but it gives me the wrong value:

[image: The overview]

I tried to use [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) on both sides, but it keep saying that the formula is invalid:

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() formula for both columns

Comment: Hey, i tried, bit says the formula is invalid. I put the image on the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't read Portuguese but I believe you need sum() in both sides of your formula, like this:

```
sum([field 1])/sum([field 2])
```

Comment: Hey, i tried, bit says the formula is invalid. I put the image on the answer